# How to display string number which is start from zero?

Tags: php, string

what I want to do is add the number in loop and get the result, my addition is correct, but the string was not correct.

here is my code:

```
$contract_records->start_no = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=($contract_records->no_of_pages);$i++){            
$start_no = $contract_records->start_no;        
$total = $start_no + $i;
var_dump($total);
```

var_dump result is:

```
int(1) int(2) int(3) int(4) int(5)
```

what I want in my result is:

```
00001
00002
00003
00004
00005
```

detail:

```
$contract_records->start_no = 00001
$contract_records->no_of_pages = 5
```

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numbers don't have a *format*. A numeric value is just the value, there are no leading zeros. Format your numbers upon output, for example using [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) or [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf).

Answer (score 4):

Use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%05d", $i);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_pad](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
    echo str_pad($i, 5, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . PHP_EOL; 

// Outputs:
// 00001
// 00002
// 00003
// 00004
// 00005
```

Comment: thank you for reply, I had try your code, but why my result become more 6 zero which is 0000000001 0000000002 0000000003 0000000004 0000000005

Comment: You must be outputting both the number 0 and the current number on each line using str_pad.